# Who did Valentine call?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, kingsman-the-secret-service

In [*Kingsman: The Secret Service*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Secret_Service), Valentine calls his friend to borrow a satellite when his own is shot down.

He asks his glasses to call "E-man"

> V-Glass, call E-man.
> E, it's V. Listen, man, I got a little hiccup on this end. I need to piggyback. One of my satellites just went down but it's right next to one of yours.

**Who is *E-man* supposed to hint to?** (Elon Musk maybe?)

Comment: Elon Musk of course.

Comment: @dna - Given that we see a Hyperloop under Kingsman HQ and Harry drives a Tesla (literally the first time it was given a product placement in a film), it's not hard to imagine that Musk was being referred to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not set in stone nor in any script I searched, but it's been said all around the web that it might probably be Elon Musk. In the absence of proof (such as script or interview), what are the hints that would confirm such hypothesis?

Even if the movie was released worlwide in 2015, at this time, Elon Musk (and others) had already planned on building [Starlink](https://www.starlink.com/)<sup>1</sup> or similar systems. The idea of internet via satellites was already on tracks, and it's a possibility that he was the inspiration for the E-Villain<sup>2</sup>, because he was the external face of the company, where others were just companies, with no one to identify to.

There's also a [hyperloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperloop) and a [Tesla vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla,_Inc.#Automotive_products) in the movie, 2 of Musk's product or idea.

---

> SpaceX is not the first to propose such a system. Similar internet-via-satellite networks are under development by privately owned OneWeb and by Boeing, while a $200m satellite leased by Facebook's Internet.org initiative, which has a similar goal of providing global internet access, was destroyed in an explosion of the SpaceX launch vehicle contracted to send it into orbit. [source](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/nov/17/elon-musk-satellites-internet-spacex)

> Elon Musk's space company has asked the federal government for permission to begin testing on an ambitious project to beam Internet service from space, a significant step forward for an initiative that could create another major competitor to Comcast, AT&T and other telecom companies. [source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/spacex-founder-files-with-government-to-provide-internet-service-from-space/2015/06/09/db8d8d02-0eb7-11e5-a0dc-2b6f404ff5cf_story.html)

---

<sup>1. Hi Elon, you want to beam internet services from space. What will you call it? Well, it's internet, it's from the sky. Skynet?</sup>

<sup>2. TV Tropes confidently asserts that it's Musk ([word of god](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Trivia/KingsmanTheSecretService#:%7E:text=E%20(the%20man%20Valentine%20calls,African%2DAmerican%20inventor%20Elon%20Musk.)))</sup>

Comment: The TVTropes website asserts (without evidence) that Matthew Vaughan has confirmed that it's Elon Musk, but I can't find a lick of proof online that actually backs that up

Comment: And if you can find that proof, then the rest of this answer becomes largely obsolete

Comment: yep, neither could I so I skipped that part.

Comment: I'm always very wary of anything that's fan-written.